# How to assign values to nested object in freemarker

Tags: html-email, freemarker

This could be simple but i couldn't find it on internet.
I have nested object in freemarker as below which has multiple key i am not able to assign value to more than one key I am able to assign value to only one key

```
<#assign modifiedObjectChng = {
    "beforeDep": {
        "range": [],
        "newTravelDate": "",
        "reissueAllowed": false,
        "changeAllowed": false,
        "maxPenality": ""
},
"afterDep": {
        "range": [],
        "newTravelDate": "",
        "reissueAllowed": false,
        "changeAllowed": false,
        "maxPenality": ""
}
}>
<#assign modifiedObjectChng = modifiedObjectChng + { "beforeDep" : {"newTravelDate" : "AAA" }}>
<#assign modifiedObjectChng = modifiedObjectChng + { "beforeDep" : {"reissueAllowed" : "BBB" }}>

${modifiedObjectChng.beforeDep.newTravelDate} //Output : error following has evaluated to null
${modifiedObjectChng.beforeDep.reissueAllowed} // gives correct result
```

My problem is how will i assign value to multiple keys i am able to do with only one key

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<#assign modifiedObjectChng = modifiedObjectChng + { "beforeDep" : modifiedObjectChng.beforeDep + {"newTravelDate" : "AAA" }}>
<#assign modifiedObjectChng = modifiedObjectChng + { "beforeDep" : modifiedObjectChng.beforeDep + {"reissueAllowed" : "BBB" }}>
```

Not very nice, but FreeMarker doesn't support modifying the objects that was passed to the template. It's more convenient if the setter methods are exposed (see `?api`), but in general it's quite odd if templates modify objects.